# Problem hosting react app at sub route of website - multiple websites one IP address NGINX

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, pm2

I am new to NGINX so this may be a simple fix, but i cant find any great documentation about what i am trying to do here.

So I have a website which is hosted on an ubuntu aws server by nginx and pm2.  my problem is that I want to serve the website at `www.mysite.com` and the react app at `www.mywebsite.com/app`.  this doesnt seem like it should be the hardest thing to do.  However I have been having problems and cannot get it to work as i would like. *(part of this is because i also wish to host an API server at `www.mywebsite.com/api` but that is a problem for after this).*   I was able to first just host the react app at `www.mysite.com` with the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 18.191.56.251;
    root /home/ubuntu/app/src;
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
}
}
```

But when i switch it to the sub route by altering the config as so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;

    location /status {
        return 200;
    }

    location /app {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://...:3011/;
    }
}
```

Then my base route `www.mywebsite.com` for the static website works fine, but `www.mywebsite.com/app` does not and "loads" a blank page but if you inspect you see that the app is unable to load some resources:

```
bundle.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
0.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

EDIT   more research:
If i examine the request for the resource i see its url is `www.mywebsite.com/static/js/XXX.js` but the static folder is at `~/app/build/static`. is this a nginx or a pm2 problem with hosting the static files?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Did you try adding a slash after the ```proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000```? i.e. proxy_pass ```http://127.0.0.1:3000/```

Answer (score 0):

So I would still love a different result then this but i figured out a workaround for this, i added the following after `location /app`:

```
location /static {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

i dont love this solution because if i end up having static content as part of other projects then it will not work, but somehow all the resources for my website are packaged within the correct proxy at `/`. so currently it is all working.